# Fear of apt-get upgrade: Will it break my website?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, apt-get

Ok, I have a website that I manage on an Ubuntu box, but I haven't updated apache2 in a while.  I would like to get up to date with the security patches etc.

The problem is that I don't have a Test or QA server or anything to "experiment" with and I don't want to knock out my website.

What are the risks of doing an apt-get update/upgrade to apache2 on a fairly active website?

Comment: You should definitely consider getting a sandbox server!

Comment: Ubuntu is based on testing/unstable repos, isn't it? There will always be a risk, IMO.

Comment: @Rob: the testing/unstable part is irrelevant.

Comment: If you're worried about things going amiss, you wouldn't be updating/upgrading unstable, would you?

Comment: Updating the Apache web server might not be the risky part. It is more complicated if php is involved.

Comment: @Rob->Not sure what you are referring to by "unstable". Maybe you can say more about that. I never mentioned upgrading to an unstable release or anything. If I issue an apt-get update/upgrade apache2, will I get an "unstable" upgrade???

Comment: @Strubbl, well I'm using php, but my first thought would be to upgrade apache, then consider a php upgrade. Frankly I'd have less concern with PHP.

Comment: I would love it if someone with actual experience could shed some light on this: like "I've done many apache upgrades on ubuntu systems, and never have any caused a site to go down after the upgrade completes" or "It's in apache's ugrade policy, that their upgrade's are backwards compatible (won't cause severe issues) with at least 3 releases" or something like that.

Comment: I've upgraded apache and php using apt-get upgrade a few times and never had any problems. HOWEVER, I do have a sandbox server for such occasions and would try it there first. Do you have the ability to make a snapshot backup of the whole system, so you could restore it if it does break?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing `apt-get update / upgrade` is considered to be very safe, because you'll only get bug fixes & security fixes.

Upgrading to a new release of ubuntu (like from 10.10 to 11.04) however might be risky. But you should be fine.

And just so you know: in case there is a problem, you can always install the previous versions of all packages.

Comment: Thanks it is helpful to have someone come out and say this.

Answer (score 1):

I've never had an apt-get (or aptitude, the preferred tool) upgrade break Apache. If you're worried, create a sandbox server as a VM on your PC, for instance using the free VirtualBox. You can make an image of your real server and run it within VB quite straightforwardly, although it will take a bit of time.